# laravel 5.8 - create & update user's profile

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm new in laravel and I'm working on a project and I want to create users with a profile for each of one but I can't find a tutorial for that to insert data from blade to table and show data from table to the user's profile. would you please recommend to me a tutorial I can follow their steps.

Comment: https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-58-crud-create-read-update-delete-tutorial-for-beginnersexample.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have simple way to update user profile, and in this case just name and email.

1. create new controller, any name

```
    public function index()
    {
        return view('usersprofile.index');
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $user->name = $request->get('name');
        $user->email = $request->get('email');
        $user->save();
        return redirect('users')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
    }
```

2. create folder usersprofile inside resource->view, and create
   index.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('users.update', Auth::user()->id) }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i>Update
    </button>
</form>
```

3. edit your route file.

```
Route::resource('users', 'YourController');
```

and you need to add `Use App\User;`